# the correct usage of "swaying to"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I have these sentences:
"What percentage of the choices do you make with full confidence? Without a part of you swaying to the alternatives? "

Is using "swaying to" correct?  or alternatively:
"...Without a part of you pointing (prompting) the alternatives"

Which one sounds better? or none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase *swaying to* is fine in that context. You could also use ***leaning toward***. The expression *leaning toward* is often used when someone is having an inward debate about some issue in their mind.

> We had to decide was whether it was a heavy handed restoration or in fact a forgery. I am [leaning toward](https://yaledailynews.com/blog/2017/10/06/the-science-of-art-conservation-dustin-dunaway/) a forgery.

I would avoid *pointing* or *prompting* – assuming I understand what you are trying to say in your original sentence.